# JQUERY Mouse over where attr matched

Tags: jquery

How can I target GB with jquery?

See here for html http://jsbin.com/opedih/1/edit

I need something like the below

```
 $("g[data-code='GB']").mouseover(function(){
     alert('test');
});
```

Comment: whats the exact problem?

Comment: looks like you forgot to add jQuery. http://jsbin.com/ugafun/1/edit

Comment: I think that you can give ID to the g tag as you would to something else.

Comment: The alert is not coming up when rolling over the targeted element. I think I have my selector wrong.

Comment: $('g[transform="150"]') try this....

Comment: Incredible... your example works fine I already added an example but, yeah, it's best you add anyway a `g` like suggested by @Scorpio

Comment: Haha...it seems I simplified the code to put on here too much...that it made it work. 

What it is...is a SVG map. I want an alert to pop up when rolling over GB. If you take a look here: http://jsbin.com/opedih/1/ You can see that GB has a data-code="GB" tag. That is what I am struggling to target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('g > path[data-code="GB"]').mouseover(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
```

Comment: I have updated the question as I had simplified my code to pop on here too much that it made it work lol.

Comment: $('g > path[data-code="GB"]').mouseover(function(){
     alert('test');  });   try if this helps...

Comment: $('g > path[data-code="GB"]').mouseover(function(){
   alert('test');
 });

Didnt work for me :-(

Comment: < http://jsbin.com/ugafun/3/edit >  Hmm take a look at this ..Its working I don't know what else can cause the issue on your side...